# wifi not working after installing 16.04 in dell latitude 3440

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, but unfortunately the wifi is not working. I am not sure whether it is a problem with the driver or the hardware.

I opened network application and switched wifi on, but it is automatically setting back off.

Network drive details:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Run a full system upgrade using USB (through your phone) or Ethernet Connection to the internet. Reboot and wifi should work.